# ¿Como puedo saber la ruta de un archivo en Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: archivo, rutas, jupyter

Cuando necesito cargar un archivo tipo .csv por ejemplo. No se como puedo conocer la ruta en la que se encuentra para usarla.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.